# grpc 1.4.3 patch & installation

Tags: yocto, grpc

Could you please help me?
I googled youcto grpc and there was a information about it and it is in master branch:
https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/67896/

So, I tried to git it using:
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky

however, I couldn't find anything related with grpc which are grpc folder and recipes-support/grpc/grpc_1.4.3.bb file at all.
(There are lots of folder in meta/recipes-support)

Could you please let know what I should do and what I did wrong thing?

Thank you.

//Daum

Comment: Dear, I just do it different way and I could do it. "git clone https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud.git". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`GRPC` is not part of `POKY` it is in `meta-iot-cloud/recipes-support/grpc/` layer.

```
git clone github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud.git
```

clone the above git to your sources/ dir path where the all other layers present like `meta-openembedded`,`poky` etc.

Then open the below path and add your layer path

```
vi build/conf/bblayers.conf
```

Comment: It works with "git clone github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud.git". Thank you so much.